# reset background color of a tablerow

Tags: android

I have a table row that I implement onclick event to display a dialog and once clicked it'll change its background color.

But after I close the popup I would like to reset its background color back to normal. I can't do this with the following silly code I copied from the web.

```
        mPrefRemindBtn=(TableRow)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pref_remind_btn);
        Drawable orgin=mPrefRemindBtn.getBackground(); 
        mPrefRemindBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPrefRemindBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125, 155, 234, 135));
                JOptionDialogEx dlg=new JOptionDialogEx(EventPreferenceActivity.this); 
                dlg.show();             

            }   

        });
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mPrefRemindBtn.setBackground(orgin);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is almost fine. Just add on Dismiss and on Cancel events and change the color from there. See: [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29)